# Google maps api only show one marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to do something easy but i dont know why it doesn't work. I have a page with a Map that shows correctly. I have a JS file that take a json with locations to show in map onload event. And it's work but only show the last marker but I don't know why. This is the js file:

```
var mymap;
var mapOptions;

function initialize() {

        mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        $.get('getlocations.php',DisplayLocations);

}

function DisplayLocations(data, status)
{
    var locations = $.parseJSON(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var loc = locations[i];
      DisplayLocation(loc);
    }   
}

function DisplayLocation(location)
{

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lon),
      map: mymap,
      title: 'Info'
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: location.des
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(mymap,marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or a link to a map that shows the issue?

Comment: Could you provide some json data?

Comment: Here you have some json:

[
{
lon: "-3.62583",
lat: "40.4395",
des: "loc1"
},
{
lon: "-25.3639",
lat: "131.045",
des: "loc2"
}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

131.045 is not a valid latitude, the maximum value allowed for latitude is 90 degrees.

> Here you have some json:
>
> [ { lon: "-3.62583", lat: "40.4395", des: "loc1" }, { lon: "-25.3639", lat: "131.045", des: "loc2" } ]